# Stripe React Native: Merchant display name cannot be an empty string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement the Stripe React Native SDK to my React Native application but I am getting an error when I present the payment sheet to the user.

I followed the tutorial on stripe's website (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native) but I keep getting the following error:

```
{"code": "Failed", "declineCode": null, "localizedMessage": "When a Configuration is passed to
PaymentSheet, the Merchant display name cannot be an empty string.", "message": "When a
Configuration is passed to PaymentSheet, the Merchant display name cannot be an empty string.",
"stripeErrorCode": null, "type": null}
```

I did not find any forum talking about this issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the same error. After rechecking the docs, I found out "merchantDisplayName" param was missing when initialising stripe payment sheet.

```
const {error} = await initPaymentSheet({
  paymentIntentClientSecret: client_secret,
  googlePay: true,
  merchantDisplayName: 'Merchant Name',
});
```

Comment: It is indeed the fix for my issue. I talked with Stripe support and they told me that: "If you're following this guide, you need to add the merchantDisplayName. It is missing from the docs"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of these [parameters](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/4474d0785c43d82e6e6278eb064a04b68d9a6c2e/paymentsheet/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/paymentsheet/PaymentSheet.kt#L333) were not set.

```
    fun configureWithSetupIntent(
        setupIntentClientSecret: String,
        configuration: Configuration? = null,
        callback: ConfigCallback
    )
```